# Visual bug with markdown and html list item

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown

The list dot is outside the container, edit question to see. Excuse if duplicate, did not find on quick search.

[image]

Using Firefox 25

It's looking correct with Chrome 31

Comment: I don't see what you are referring too. What browser and which version are you using?

Comment: Repro in Firefox 26.

Comment: So can I... the solution would be adding `list-style-position:inside` to the `li` elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<li>The list dot is outside the container, edit question to see. Excuse if duplicate, did not find on quick search.
```

You're using improper syntax. You're not creating a *list*, you're only creating a *list item*, so the proper styles that would accompany the bullet points is not being applied, because the parent list does not exist.

Proper HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>The list dot is outside the container, edit question to see. Excuse if duplicate, did not find on quick search.
</ul>
```

Which produces this (note the extra padding on the left side):

> - The list dot is outside the container, edit question to see. Excuse if duplicate, did not find on quick search.

Comment: Additionally, mixing markdown and HTML elements can sometimes lead to weird results. When in doubt, use Markdown on SE sites.

Comment: In any case, SE should be able to handle at least keeping it inside the container no?

Comment: @Cruncher I don't see why. That's not even valid HTML. I don't know any people who write CSS to compensate for invalid HTML structures.